# List all events which I can use?

Tags: jquery

How can I list all events which I can use with jQuery? E.g. *click*, *change*, *selectmenuchange*...

```
$('body').on('selectmenuchange', '.foo', function() {
    ...
});
```

I already searched on http://api.jquery.com

[image]

I went through all of them, but I was even unable to find *selectmenuchange*. It seems like the API is not fully documented.

How can I list all possible events?

Comment: What are you expecting *selectmenuchange* to do?

Comment: It should react if a user changes the option of a select. @Liam

Comment: You've accepted TJs answer below. So you statement above is lacking. It's not a select it's a Jquery UI select plugin, which is an important distinction. If you have questions on Jquery UI I'd advise you include the code your using to initialise the plugin and the tag [tag:jquery-ui]

Comment: I was not aware of it being a jQuery UI select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I list all possible events?

You can't. The jQuery API page just lists commonly-known events, but you can define your own; a comprehensive list is impossible.

In the case of `selectmenuchange`, it's a [jQuery UI event](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#event-change) (not that other libs or code couldn't use that name if they wanted).

For instance, here's a `foobar` event:

```js
$(document).on("foobar", "div", function() {
  console.log("Got the event");
});
$("#target").trigger("foobar");
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's not 100% clear to me that this is what the OP is getting at. It could be but it could be something else entirely.

Comment: @Liam - "How can I list all possible events?" seems fairly clear to me, but... :-)

Comment: Ah, that wasn't in your answer before! :) It's more this is the Jqeury UI event, maybe, but maybe not.